# In JavaScript, how would I retain the spaces in a sentence if I split it into an array, then join it?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm doing a coderbyte challenge with these instructions:

Using the JavaScript language, have the function LetterChanges(str) take the str parameter being passed and modify it using the following algorithm. Replace every letter in the string with the letter following it in the alphabet (ie. c becomes d, z becomes a). Then capitalize every vowel in this new string (a, e, i, o, u) and finally return this modified string.

My code does what the instructions say, but it doesn't retain the spaces of the original sentence.

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var chars = str;
    var newStr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (/[a-y]/ig.test(chars[i])) {
            newStr[i] = String.fromCharCode(chars[i].charCodeAt(0) + 1);

            if (/[aeiou]/ig.test(newStr[i])) {
                newStr[i] = newStr[i].toUpperCase();
            }
       } else if (/[z]/ig.test(chars[i])) {
            newStr[i] = "A";
       }
    }

    return newStr.join(''); 
}

LetterChanges("Argument goes here"); // result should be: BshvnfOUhpftIfsf
```

Is there a way to keep the spaces from the original string?

Comment: That results in spaces between every character when I do that.

Comment: BTW if you'd like to see alternative solutions http://stackoverflow.com/q/18036270/1331430

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
else newStr[i]= chars[i];
```

To the end of the if/else